Why are metals with unpaired electrons not as reactive as radicals?
I've always read that free radicals are unstable and last for a short time before dimerizing. Yet many metals, especially ferromagnetic ones have unpaired electrons and are not classified as radicals, nor are they as reactive. Why does this occur?

You need to remembre that metals are usually really different from molecules given that they're usually organized in lattices and thus they have a band-like structure of energy levels rather than spearated levels like radicals.

It is in general wrong to assume that metals have "unpaired" electrons, because to be so you would assume a discrete number of energy levels.

If this was about complexes, it would likely work fine, about metallic phases, not so much.

And there are stable free radicals, e.g., NO2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_oxide), ClO2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_dioxide), and triplet oxygen, the more stable state of O2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triplet_oxygen).

@Mithoron yeah, you are right, I assumed Maya was talking of condensed phases but complexes are another kind of beast. In that case the treatment is basically the same as for molecules and there are tons of molecules in triplet (or some other open shell configuration) ground state as  DrMoishe Pippik commented

Would gas-phase single metal ions (e.g. in a vacuum environment) react as radicals?

To be honest if you isolate metal ions in the gas phase at low pressure probably you will observe just the radicals. It you hit them with an energy source, let's say photons of the right Energy, you might make them ions. Check if there are experimental studies of atomic metallic beams, this is is the only context where the reactivity of "radical" metals is defined.
